# Is the buoyant force decreasing in upper layer the deeper water?

Tags: forces, buoyancy

I'm asking about a real experiment. As in this I have read in an answer in this site which is [What atomic forces are acting to resist me pushing an air filled bottle underwater?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/406125/what-atomic-forces-are-acting-to-resist-me-pushing-an-air-filled-bottle-underwatthe). As in ben51's answer buoyant force is due to higher density of water and high repulsive force of water particles in the deep of water for the overlying water's weight. So if I push a block whose density is less than water to the lowest level of water providing block wouldn't break in that pressure. I now remove the down-directed force of my hand. So as the block is getting up would the buoyant force decrease as the block rises up  and a decreasing force would act on the block as it rises from the lowest layer of water?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bouyant force is given by:

$$ F(d) = \rho_w(d) \, V(d) \, g(d) $$

where all of the three quantities in the equation are functions of the depth $d$. They are all functions of the depth because:

- the density of the water $\rho_w$ increases with depth because the pressure compresses the water. This isn't a bit effect because water isn't very compressible but it is significant. I think the water density increase is around 5% at the bottom of the deepest ocean.
- the volume displaced decreases with depth because the pressure compresses your object as well as compressing the water around it. We can write the volume of the object as $m/\rho_o(d)$, where $m$ is the (constant) mass of the object, to move all the density dependence into the density of the object.
- the acceleration due to gravity increases with depth because we are getting closer to the centre of the Earth. It increases because the rock and iron core below us has a higher density than the water above us.

So rewriting our equation as suggested above gives:

$$ F(d) = \frac{\rho_w(d)}{\rho_o(d)} \, m \, g(d) $$

The trouble is that all the depth dependent quantities vary in complicated ways so there is no simple answer as to how $F$ varies with depth. If your object is incompressible then $\rho_o$ is constant, and since both $\rho_w(d)$ and $g(d)$ increase with depth that means the buoyant force *increases* with increasing depth. I suspect this is the answer that you had in mind.

But suppose your object is highly compressible (like an air bubble). That means $\rho_o(d)$ increases strongly with depth, and this means that the buoyant force *decreases* with increasing depth.

Answer (score 3):

The buoyant force acting on an object is $\rho_{water}\times V_{object} \times g$, where $V$ is the volume of the object. Here, you can see that pressure has no effect on the buoyant force acting on the object.  What determines whether the object floats or sinks is the $F_{net}$ acting on the object.  $F_{net}=F_{buoyant}-F_{hand}-F_{weight}$.  Hence, if $F_{net}>0$, then the object floats, while if $F_{net}<0$, then the object rises up.  If $F_{net}=0$, the object remains stationary in the water.

Comment: @qulckmaths I'm asking about does the buoyant force decrease as the block rises in water?

Comment: please see my previous comment

Comment: No as Quickmaths says it only depends on the local density of the water (and the size of the object). Although there is more pressure pushing up at greater depth, there is also a column of water above the object pushing down.

Comment: ps. In real life the buoyancy of say a submarine does vary with depth because of changes in water density due to temperature and salinity changes

Comment: Yes, but in theory we always assume that density is uniform throughout :)

Comment: @QuIcKmAtHs my question is actually about reality.

Comment: @MartinBeckett I'm asking with reference to the question https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/406125/what-atomic-forces-are-acting-to-resist-me-pushing-an-air-filled-bottle-underwat

Comment: @MartinBeckett I read the first answer and asked it.

Comment: @QuIcKmAtHs now please see the question now. I've edited it.

Comment: As my answer has addressed, the object only moves up or down depending on the net force acting on the object.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that buoyant force acts upwards but I'm asking about its magnitude as the block rises up in water. I mean a force vs position of block diagram is helpful in the particular case in my question @quickmaths

Comment: As in ben51's answer I found the density of water is more in the lower layer of water due to the pressure of overlying water. So the water molecules are more packed up in the lower layer of water.

Comment: So I'm asking about the magnitude of force at different positions of the block inside water. Rather than the average force.

Comment: @quickmaths as I'm  asking about it when the density of block is lower than water. Please see the question properly.

Comment: I doubt if ben51’s answer mentioned anything about varying density.  The magnitude of the forces at the top and bottom of the block can vary depending on the motion of the block.  If the block is being held stationary in water, then the forces acting on the top and bottom of the block would certainly be equal.